# AI assistence options on linux

Tags: speech-recognition

I just saw my friend talking to remote control of a smart TV. Asking it to search "something on Youtube". My friend did that with local language and even with a mild accent.

I started looking for a voice activated assistant & surprisingly couldn't find anything. What options do i have on Linux particularly on Ubuntu?

- To give basic commands via speech recognition.
- Open source ofc.
- How can we do these stuff which a super marketed electronic with a bottom layer cpu can do?

Microsoft pc there are countless different options, for apple very narrow propriety licensed trade marked oprtions, i have even saw some browser based experimental assistants.

What an ubuntu user has ? 
Is this a completely untouched territory ?

Answer (score 0):

After failed installation attempts with depreciated sound to text programs assembled by linux community a decade ago.

I stumbled upon to Mycroft AI. Looks promising. Community oriented organisation. Simple AI assistant for Linux with a real API.

Please post if there are any other options. whatever is still working and reasonable to use with a modern distro.